# How to create a receipt / facture?

Tags: templates

I would like to make a standard template for receipts.

It should have the usual stuff, i.e.: name, date, concept, amount given, etc. since they could be used for payments such as rent or just plain deposits.

Do you any package that could take care of this?  Do you have any ideas on mind how to make this template?

Comment: could you give some more details- perhaps a screenshot of what you would like to see?

Comment: [ctan search](http://www.ctan.org/search) with your keywords gives me [facture](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/facture). Give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice) package: it works well for me.

Comment: See this example: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/invoice